# What does 'plug their noses' mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrases

When serious actors take on jobs involving comic books and hours in machines and makeup, they generally **plug their noses** and take the paycheck. 
Does it mean that they are unwilling to do that but had to accept it?

Comment: It smells bad but they do it anyway.

Comment: in this case it may smell bad, but is is asphyxiating!

Answer (score 1):

To 'plug one's nose' seems to be a variant of the common idiom 'to hold one's nose', meaning to squeeze one's nostrils with the fingers to avoid an unpleasant smell. Figuratively it means to overcome or ignore one's distaste while doing something unpleasant or shameful because of necessity (such as lack of money).

Answer (score 0):

**plug their noses**? Actors literally do such during make-up application.

> When serious actors [Downey] take on jobs involving comic books and hours in
>   machines and makeup, they generally **plug their noses [literally ... for the hours of make-up application] and take the
>   paycheck**. Mr. Downey is having none of that. At 43 he is thrilled to
>   be fit enough — he had spent the morning with the living room
>   furniture pushed aside for instruction in wing chun, a Chinese martial
>   art built on aggressive, close combat — to play a hero. He views the
>   Big Comic Book Movie as a kind of arrival.  [NYT article on RDjr)](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/04/20/movies/20carr.html)

Mr Downey finds no objection to the genre ... and enjoys the paycheck as well!

[image: ironman]